# How to get the first parent node child nodes name value alone?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

Am having below xml file structure.

```
<BookStore>
    <Book Id="1">
      <Subject>
        <Rank ID="Chemistry">
            <a>A</a>
        </Rank>
        <Rank ID="Physics">
            <b>B</b>
        </Rank>
      </Subject>
    </Book>
    <Book Id="2">
      <Subject>
        <Rank ID="Science">
            <a>C</a>
        </Rank>
        <Rank ID="English">
            <b>D</b>
        </Rank>
      </Subject>
    </Book>
</BookStore>
```

I want to get the Chemistry and physics value alone while iterating. How do I parse and get that value alone.

I have tried with the below code. So I got 4 values.

```
var platformNodeList1 = xmlSourceFile.SelectNodes("BookStore/Book/Subject/Rank");
```

can anyone please provide me your valuable suggestion on this?

can anyone please tell me how to bring the .... in a string through c# code?

Comment: can anyone please tell me how to bring the <Book Id="1">....</Book> in a string through c# code?

Comment: `xmlSourceFile.SelectSingleNode("BookStore/Book[@Id='1']").OuterXml`

Answer (score 0):

You can parse using LINQ to XML and find the elements you want using LINQ:

```
 var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

 var firstBook = doc.Descendants("Book")
     .Single(e => (string)e.Attribute("Id") == "1");

 var firstBookRanks = doc.Descendants("Book")
     .Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("Id") == "1")
     .Descendants("Rank");

 var chemistry = doc.Descendants("Rank")
     .Single(e => (string)e.Attribute("ID") == "Chemistry");

 var physics = doc.Descendants("Rank")
     .Single(e => (string)e.Attribute("ID") == "Physics");
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to adjust your XPath query to something like...

```
var platformNodeList1 = xmlSourceFile.SelectNodes("BookStore/Book[@Id='1']/Subject/Rank");
```

or if you want to iterate books too...

```
var books = xmlSourceFile.SelectNodes("BookStore/Book");

foreach(var book in books) {
    var ranks = book.SelectNodes("Subject/Rank");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use XML Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "<BookStore>" +
                "<Book Id=\"1\">" +
                  "<Subject>" +
                    "<Rank ID=\"Chemistry\">" +
                        "<a>A</a>" +
                    "</Rank>" +
                    "<Rank ID=\"Physics\">" +
                        "<b>B</b>" +
                    "</Rank>" +
                  "</Subject>" +
                "</Book>" +
                "<Book Id=\"2\">" +
                  "<Subject>" +
                    "<Rank ID=\"Science\">" +
                        "<a>C</a>" +
                    "</Rank>" +
                    "<Rank ID=\"English\">" +
                        "<b>D</b>" +
                    "</Rank>" +
                  "</Subject>" +
                "</Book>" +
                "</BookStore>";

            XDocument xmlSourceFile = XDocument.Parse(input);

            var platformNodeList1 = xmlSourceFile.Descendants("Rank").Select(x => x.Attribute("ID").Value).ToList();
        }
    }
}​
```